# Not able to include Authorize.net SDK inside XCode 5 project

Tags: xcode, sdk, authorize.net, xcode5

I followed the instructions here http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/ios/ but am not able to include this project into my code. When I try to build using the build.sh I get errors on the console so I dragged the XCode project from Authorize.net SDK to my project as shown in the image. I am using XCode 5 DP6

[image]

Comment: What type of error you got in console????

Answer (score 0):

I recommend check this project:  https://github.com/sibahota059/AuthorizeNetPaymentTest/tree/master This sample only can be compiled and run without any error. it's just the sample code but it's a beginning.